# Synthesis of bromobutane

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, halides

What will be the cost efficient and high yielding method of synthesis for 1-bromobutane?

I can react butanol with $\ce{HBr}$ but I am worried butanol is not present at the moment in lab. But I need to hurry and make bromobutane.

Comment: Well, clearly what you _do_ have in the lab will the rate determining step. What potential candidates have you got in the inventory?

Answer (score 7):

Current prices are about 34 € (500 g) for 1-bromobutane and 32 € (500 mL) for 1-butanol in decent lab quality.

The most cost efficient method is ordering 1-bromobutane from a chemical supplier of your choice!

On a **technical** scale, one would probably react 1-butene with anhydrous hydrogen bromide under radical conditions, using peroxides or UV light to initiate homolytic cleavage of the $\ce{H-Br}$ bond.

Comment: Bromine radical is selective. You cannot expect to obtain a high yield of 1-bromobutane from such a reaction. Besides, such reactions are a mess to purify and this will be very tedious and difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Start with butanal or butanoic acid, reduce them with LiAlH4 and aqueous work-up and you have 1-butanol.
If you have 1-butene, you do hydroboration/oxidation then phosphorus tribromide.

Are you trying to make a Grignard? or a substitution reaction?